# What's the name of a mortise lock that uses no key?

Tags: doors, lock

I need to buy a door lock that uses handles and that requires a pocket—the mortise—to be cut into the door.

Something like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HXIYBCA) or like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NCK79XM).

But one that uses no key nor any other locking mechanism. So I need something basic, for the door at my room - there is no need to lock it.

I need to search for this on the internet so I need to be able to search specifically for this kind of product, is there a particular name for this? It would improve my search results a lot. At this moment, all my searches return a gazillion of products that I don't need

Maybe it's "Door Lever"? Or "Door Leverset"? Searching for the last one seems to have better results, yet too many of them use a key.

Comment: Your links show cylinder locks not mortise locks. They make passage latchsets for mortise locks too.

Comment: @LeeSam: Thanks, but searching on Amazon for "cylinder lock" returns a lot of cylinders with key and without the handles, like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/1-3-Long-Cylinder-Lock-Antique/dp/B001DT1682/). But searching for "cylinder passage" returns much better results, maybe this is closer to the right name for this kind of product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you want is "passage" - passage sets are made for hallways and closets without locks.  So if you search for "passage latchset" or "passage mortise latchset" you should find what you need.

Comment: It’s called “Latchset” not “Lockset”, but yes, +1 for identifying the function as passage.

Comment: I would add "passage door handle set" or even "passage door lever" for the more modern style with the lever instead of  a knob.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to narrow down the results only to those not using keys nor other locking mechanisms? Is there a naming distinction between Passage Latchsets that use keys and those not using keys?

Comment: Passage means no locks / keys